# The New Robotics Site has just launched!

Tags: discussion

For those who are still interested in **Robotics** I'm happy to announce that the [Robotics Stack Exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) site went into [public beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146113/138432) on the 7th November 2012.

Although many [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposals related to Robotics have failed in the past, the latest combined [Robotics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics) was created in April, completed the new 40 question [definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) in September, reached full commitment in October. The *private* beta site was created in late October and after [an extension](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/72/37) to help get it into shape, went public.

The final push for committers was completed with support from a dozen or so people here on Electronics, so hopefully the site will be of interested to other EE regulars. *Robotics* certainly appreciates the contribution already made by EE regulars.

If you are interested in Robotics and think you could contribute towards making the beta a success, we would love to see you over on *Robotics*. Whether you are an expert willing to lend your expertise or a hobbyist with questions to ask, I think the new [*Robotics*](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) site will be a great resource and I look forward to seeing people there.

Comment: I am hacking at this some to make it a pure advertisement.

Comment: Fair enough, can't complain at that. 8') I've submitted my *wrapper* question as [another question](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2461/3774), since I still think it is a valid one.

Comment: work sidetracked me, sorry, I was going to suggest that.

Comment: I don't know what some of what you said means. You mention *the* 40 question definition phase like we're all supposed to know what that means, what "committers" are, etc. Is the process of a new proposal becoming a full site explained somewhere? If so, you should link to it since I doubt I'm not the only one who has no idea how this process works and therefore much of what you are talking about.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - The details of how Area 51 works are documented in its [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), so that would be a good place to start. As with all stack exchange sites, the Area 51 FAQ is linked at the top of every Area 51 page, such as the one I linked to.

Comment: @OlinLathrop He went into some detail about how successful the site creation was because there was an attempt in the past to create such a site and it failed.  Those who were involved may not want to participate if it was simply going to fail again, so he spent some extra words explaining that it's unlikely to fail again due to some specific circumstances.  You can safely ignore all that and simply read the first paragraph, and visit the first link if it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

With our 10 year anniversary coming up, I just wanted to take the opportunity to thank all of those people here on *Electronics* Stack Exchange who have helped *Robotics* grow. Whether it be committing to the proposal, running our community ads, or joining our community.

I thank you all, and I look forward to continued future cooperation.